# Most efficient way to manage data on local storage of a web browser

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've implemented a 'Task-Board' where all new tasks are added instantly to the page when pressing on the "Save" button. In addition, the data saved in the web browser local storage and when the page loads - the data is updated. The program works, but I feel it's a little complicated especially in:

1. I save all containers in an array and then save in local storage.
2. When I remove a container - I've to search in the whole array - but - when I remove a container I don't have to search between all containers. Maybe there is a way to pass a reference and when container removed I'll be able to delete it from local storage without searching in the whole array?

Code:

```
**window.onload = (event) => {
if(localStorage.getItem('notes')){
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes')).forEach(element => {
createNote(element);
});;
}**

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click',function(){

var mission =
 {     
    text: document.getElementById('textarea').value,
    date: document.getElementById('date').value,
    time: document.getElementById('time').value
 };

  if(mission.text !== "" && mission.date !== ""){

    **if(!localStorage.getItem('notes')) {
      notesArray=[];
      notesArray.push(mission);
      localStorage.setItem('notes',JSON.stringify(notesArray));
    }
    else{
     var notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
     notes.push(mission);
     localStorage.setItem('notes',JSON.stringify(notes));
    }
    createNote(mission);**
  }

  });// end "save" button listener. 

function createNote(mission){

const rows = document.getElementById('rows');
const cell = document.createElement('div'); 
const id = document.createAttribute('id');
id.value = "div-cell";
cell.setAttributeNode(id);
cell.innerHTML = '<button id="remove-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Right 
Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><textarea> 
</textarea><div><input><input></div>';

const [textarea, dateinput, timeinput] = cell.querySelectorAll('textarea, input'); 

textarea.value = mission.text;
dateinput.value = mission.date;
timeinput.value = mission.time;

rows.appendChild(cell);

**cell.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
 if(mission.text == array[i].text && mission.date == array[i].date && mission.time == array[i].time)
 array.splice(i,1);

}
localStorage.setItem('notes',JSON.stringify(array));
rows.removeChild(cell);**
});
```

I know it's a little long, so I've bolded the important parts. Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Have you considered creating a separate key for each container? (e.i. `container:1`, `container:2`, etc.)

Comment: not answering your question directly: #1 just be aware that browsers are restricting localStorage and cookies even from 1st party; #2 remember to add a polyfill for localStorage and check if `localStorage` exists before use it; #3 instead of holding in localSTorage, have you thought about an easy to use Database... try [FaunaDB](https://fauna.com/resources)

Comment: Hi, yes, but there is no limit to the number of containers - too many keys... and when for example 'container 1' will be deleted, how should I know that this key is available

Comment: Hi, I know the best way to manage such amounts of data in DB, but the local storage is the task requirement...

Comment: I've always liked https://github.com/localForage/localForage localForage for localStorage related stuff, but to comment on your question: I would just try to create a horizontal data-structure and pass the key of the container in the delete action